# Cannot make an image button on WeChat mini-program

Tags: html, wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I want to make buttons with image icons on WeChat mini-program. For example, play/pause, next, previous buttons in media player.
I tried as html:

```
<button>
    <image src="../image/play.svg"></image>
</button>
```

But I cannot see any image on button.
How to make an image button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image buttons, just use `<image>` tag.
For example:

```html
<image src="../image/play.svg" bindTap="play()"></image>
```

And set some button-like styles using WXSS.

```css
image {
    background: lightblue;
}
image:hover {
    background: lightgrey;
}
```

Of course, your icon image should have transparent background.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it with

```
<button bindtap = "mytap">
     <image src = '../../image/search-icon.png' style=" width: 35rpx;height: 35rpx;"></image>
     Search
</button>
```

You can also put inside the button only the image element

```
<button bindtap = "mytap">
     <image src = '../../image/search-icon.png' style=" width: 35rpx;height: 35rpx;"> </image>
</button>
```

In javascript or typescript files put:

```
Page({

  //...
  mytap(){
    console.log("clic")
  }
})
```

For more details you can consult: [Implement picture button in WeChat Mini Program](https://www.programmersought.com/article/44993916214/)